# How can i get BBC iPlayer to work on Windows Phone 7.x?

Tags: lumia, 7.5, streaming

I have a Nokia 610 running WP7.5. I want to listen to radio catchup but while I can navigate to the page and click 'play' in IE, nothing happens. I *can* listen to live radio but not anything on catchup, which is all done through iPlayer I think.

There is no iPlayer app and WP is not an approved mobile device apparently.

Is there a technical limitation or is it an arbitrary lack of support that could be worked around?

(and does anyone know if WP8 is any better, maybe I could just upgrade)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like it's your lucky day. :) http://www.pocket-lint.com/news/119871-bbc-iplayer-coming-windows-phone-7-8

Answer (score 3):

No timescale at the moment but have a read of this

http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/technology-21672033

> Handsets running Microsoft's mobile operating system cannot currently
>   access the catch-up TV and radio service.
>
> Rather than create a native app the BBC plans to allow a web-based
>   version of iPlayer to be accessed via a live tile - or square icon -
>   on the Windows Phone home screen.
>
> By wrapping the iPlayer mobile website together with its proprietary
>   Media Player plug-in, the broadcaster can offer access to streamed
>   feeds of its material but will still not be able to let users download
>   programmes for offline use - as is the case with its iOS app.

So no. There's no way of watching iPlayer on WP right now but should be coming soon

Comment: This is good information but doesn't really answer the asker's question.  This might be better suited as a comment than an answer.

Comment: Well it does answer it, if you'd read the link you'd see how BBC are planning to bring iPlayer to BBC.

Also, not that it really has anything to do with you, I don't have the option to leave a comment on the question. Don't let it ruin your day

Comment: Hi @Mike, welcome to the site. Link only answers aren't usually that helpful on their own. Please consider editing your answer to include an excerpt. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The only way to get iPlayer working on Windows Phone 7.x is to convince BBC to write a version of iPlayer that works on that particular OS.

The only people who could tell you if it's a technical limitation is BBC itself.

There are no work-arounds. It's likely a lack of resources at BBC that have thus far prevented them from porting iPlayer to WP7. And given that WP8 is already released, I don't think it's likely they're going to write an app for both WP 8 and WP7.

Answer (score 0):

BBC iPlayer has just been [released](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/store/app/bbc-iplayer/4ca944d4-2c9d-47a0-a153-731b67b69b80) for Windows Phone 8.

They had [this](http://www.bbc.co.uk/blogs/internet/posts/Window-8-Phone-iPlayer-Microsoft) to say about Windows Phone 7:

> Unfortunately, platform limitations with Windows Phone 7.5 have meant
>   we've been unable to provide the same quality playback experience as
>   on Windows Phone 8. This led to the joint decision not to make BBC
>   iPlayer available on Windows Phone 7.5.

Answer (score 0):

As of writing this reply in May 2017, bbc will suspend all iplayer apps for windows phone entirely as it is not worth their while doing more with it for windows phone.
They claim you can still watch on your browser.
However, this will only work for windows phone 10 OS.
They continue to make apps for iphone and android as these are more successful mobile OS's and have bigger market shares.
And I think there is no problem viewing on any Ubuntu or Linux-like OS browsers.
It is only all windows work they have stopped.
This is not peculiar to bbc as most serious app developers cant be bothered catering to windows phone in general and it has been a bit of a disaster for Microsoft.
I am only using windows phone right now to reply here as my kids laughed and refused to use it.